# Python - POST Multiple Records in one API Call

Tags: python, json, api

I'm using Python 3 with an API to send a single JSON payload like this which works fine but slow because I have 200 items to send regularly:

```
{
  "first_name":"Ellen",
  "address_country":"US"
}
```

I've checked and I can send this payload manually and it creates two records which is what I need:

```
{
    ["first_name":"Ellen",
    "address_country":"US"],

    ["first_name":"John",
    "address_country":"US"]

}
```

But I can't seem to programatically generate the multiple records. Currently my code is:

```
payload = {}
payload['first_name'] = "Ellen"
payload['address_country'] = "US"
json_payload = json.dumps(payload)
```

How do I add a second record to the payload, I'm keep overwriting it..  I essentially want to iterate through my array building up my payload and send x number of results at once rather than each array iteration sending a single payload.

Okay so thank you to everyone who replied but it didn't fix the issue, I get a JSON payload which looks like the following which is what I think you meant:

```
[
    {"first_name":"Ellen",
    "address_country":"US"},

    {"first_name":"John",
    "address_country":"US"}

]
```

But the server throws back a error code 400 saying none of the fields are there (which they are).  I assume that their API can only accept one input per request..  :-(

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Is it a list? a dict?

Comment: The JSON you suggest sending is not valid, nor it is exists in Python :)

Comment: You're right, apologies - I was misreading the body as the return from the API - looks like the API can only take one request at a time.  Thank you for taking the time to reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the right signs :)

```
[
    {"first_name":"Ellen",
    "address_country":"US"},
    {"first_name":"John",
    "address_country":"US"}
]
```

To do it line by line:

```
import json
payload = []
current_person = {}
current_person['first_name'] = 'Ellen'
current_person['address_country'] = 'US'
payload.append(current_person)
current_person['first_name'] = 'Ronnie'
current_person['address_country'] = 'Canada'
payload.append(current_person)
json_payload = json.dumps(payload)
```

Or even:

```
persons = [('Ronnie', 'Canada'), ('Ellen', 'US')]
json_payload = []
for name, country in persons:
     json_payload.append({'name': name, 'country': country})
```

Comment: This was going to be my exact answer, you just typed a bit faster than I :D

Comment: This worked perfectly to create a list of all my api calls - sadly the API only takes one record at a time damn it!